Does the continuity of the second order mixed partial derivative imply the continuity of the partial derivative of $f$
Theorem. $f(x,y):\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ is a function, and $f$ has partial derivatives $f_x$, $f_y$, $f_{xy}$, $f_{yx}$. Moreover, $f_{xy}$ and $f_{yx}$ are continuous. Then $f_{xy}=f_{yx}$.
I am trying to understanding the change of sequence of higher order derivatives. In my thinking the questions comes to me: If $f_{xy}$ and $f_{yx}$ are continuous, then $f_x$ and $f_y$ exists, but are $f_x$ and $f_y$ continuous?
This questions claims that $f_x$ and $f_y$ are continuous but I can not see why.
I know if $g$ is two variable function and $g_x, g_y$ are continuous, then $g$ is differentiable and so continuous. But in this question we do not know the continuous of $f_{xx}$ ($f_{yy}$), so we cannot get the continuous of $f_x$ ($f_y$) by using $f_{yx}$'s ($f_{xy}$'s) continuity.
Thank you in advance.

Please add enough info that we do not need to follow a link.

@Steen82: Ok. It is my fault. And now I think I am getting it right.

The claim is false. Let $g\colon\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ be any differentiable function whose derivative is not continuous (say, at $0$) — plenty of standard examples of this phenomenon have appeared numerous times on this site.  Now set $f(x,y)=g(x)+g(y)$. Then $f_{xy}=0=f_{yx}$ everywhere, and yet $f_x(x,y) = g'(x)$ and $f_y(x,y)=g'(y)$, so $f_x$ and $f_y$ are not continuous at the origin.

great answer and what I suspected, but real life prevented me from being sure.

Thanks. Set $f(x,y)=g(x)+g(y)$ is genius.
